# Why is temperature vibration?

Tags: solid-state-physics, temperature

Why do the atoms in a crystal vibrate at finite temperature?

Answer (score 1):

> Why is temperature vibration?

Atoms - electrons, particles etc. - vibrate, rotate, spin, etc. By hitting something else (other particles) a part of the vibration is handed over as an amount of energy. This new particle will now try to vibrate along. It will be speeded up while the original one will be slowed down. They will eventually find an equilibrium and vibrate equily.

This particle could be in the outer layer of your hand, and it now vibrates. You can feel that. To describe that feeling we call it *temperature*. If it vibrates violently, it might break loose from the surrounding atoms - maybe breaking molecular bonds and other connections. Your skin is being damaged. You feel this too and this is hardwired in us as pain. To be able to talk about this, we call this to be *burned*. And so on.

> Why do the atoms in a crystal vibrate at finite temperature?

From the start they have some energy, shown as vibration, rotation, spin etc. If all that energy is lost, they stand still. We call this situation *absolute zero* temperature.

Temperature is just the word for the macroscale version of vibration of many, many, many particles. People gave it such name to be able to talk about the largescale effect of all the vibrations in everything around us.